# Magento 2 Creating Order for new customer Throws Exception "The value of attribute Account No must be set"

Tags: magento2, orders, customer-attribute

When I create a new order for new customer and submit the order it shows the exception

> The value of  attribute "Account No" must be set

[image]

`account_no` is the required attribute for customer table that means It needs to be filled so I added the custom field in the customer account Information section on order create page so that the user can give the `account_no` 
[image]

Now I'm stuck on how to pass the new customer account number so that it creates the customer with `account_no` and save the order . I tried using the events

***sales_order_place_before
sales_order_save_before
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_item_before***

```
<event name="adminhtml_customer_prepare_save">
    <observer name="account_num_customer_save_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerSaveBefore" />
</event>




<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class CustomerSaveBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {

        protected $_helper;


        public function __construct(
            \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        ) {

            $this->_helper= $helper;
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            /**
             * @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
             */

            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
            echo "<pre>";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added **di.xml** with

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create"/>
```

**Create.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder;
 class Create extends \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create
{
     /**
     * Prepare customer data for order creation.
     *
     * Create customer if not created using data from customer form.
     * Create customer billing/shipping address if necessary using data from customer address forms.
     * Set customer data to quote.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function _prepareCustomer()
    {
     //   $this->_logger->critical('accunt no: '.$this->getData('account/account_no'));
     //   $this->_logger->critical('here now gg....');
        if ($this->getQuote()->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /** @var $store \Magento\Store\Model\Store */
        $store = $this->getSession()->getStore();
        $customer = $this->getQuote()->getCustomer();
         if ($customer->getId() && !$this->_customerIsInStore($store)) {
            /** Create a new customer record if it is not available in the specified store */
            /** Unset customer ID to ensure that new customer will be created */
            $customer->setId(null)
                ->setStoreId($store->getId())
                ->setWebsiteId($store->getWebsiteId())
                ->setCreatedAt(null);
            $customer = $this->_validateCustomerData($customer);
        } else if (!$customer->getId()) {
            /** Create new customer */
            $customerBillingAddressDataObject = $this->getBillingAddress()->exportCustomerAddress();
            $customer->setSuffix($customerBillingAddressDataObject->getSuffix())
                ->setFirstname($customerBillingAddressDataObject->getFirstname())
                ->setLastname($customerBillingAddressDataObject->getLastname())
                ->setMiddlename($customerBillingAddressDataObject->getMiddlename())
                ->setPrefix($customerBillingAddressDataObject->getPrefix())
                ->setStoreId($store->getId())
                ->setWebsiteId($store->getWebsiteId())
                ->setEmail($this->_getNewCustomerEmail())
                ->setCustomAttribute('account_no', $this->_getNewCustomerAccountNo());
            $customer = $this->_validateCustomerData($customer);
        }
        $this->getQuote()->setCustomer($customer);
         if ($this->getBillingAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()) {
            $this->_prepareCustomerAddress($this->getQuote()->getCustomer(), $this->getBillingAddress());
            $address = $this->getBillingAddress()->setCustomerId($this->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getId());
            $this->setBillingAddress($address);
        }
        if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && $this->getShippingAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()) {
            $this->_prepareCustomerAddress($this->getQuote()->getCustomer(), $this->getShippingAddress());
            $address = $this->getShippingAddress()->setCustomerId($this->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getId());
            $this->setShippingAddress($address);
        }
        $this->getBillingAddress()->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $this->getQuote()->updateCustomerData($this->getQuote()->getCustomer());
         $customer = $this->getQuote()->getCustomer();
        $origAddresses = $customer->getAddresses(); // save original addresses
        $customer->setAddresses([]);
        $customerData = $this->customerMapper->toFlatArray($customer);
        $customer->setAddresses($origAddresses); // restore original addresses
        foreach ($this->_createCustomerForm($customer)->getUserAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if (isset($customerData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()])) {
                $quoteCode = sprintf('customer_%s', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
                $this->getQuote()->setData($quoteCode, $customerData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()]);
            }
        }
         return $this;
    }
     /**
     * Retrieve new customer account number.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getNewCustomerAccountNo()
    {
        return $this->getData('account/account_no');
    }
 }
```